# Split view in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to create an iPad app wherein I need to maintain a split view throughout the app. In the split view, the left view is static and the rightview changes according to the selection of left view. The right view in turn might contain toolbars through which I can navigate to new views, But the left view always remains same.

I might have gone in with a split view but the problem is the left view is not table view but I want to use a customised view here. Is it acceptable to do this?

Please suggest if there are any better ways make a split view without using the default split view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A split view controller can have any type of view in each of its 'panes', the standard template has a table view but there is no requirement to do so. Start with the template and then edit the master view controller so it's a subclass of `UIViewController`, you can also remove or edit the XIB as you require.